# How to remove special characters in start and end of string using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a string with text like:

```
\n\thttp://exam\nple.com/\t\n\r.
```

How to delete special characters only from start and end of string in Kotlin and don't touch characters in middle of line?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`.trim()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim.html) function on `CharSequence` (which `String` implements), it will remove all leading and trailing whitespace. So assuming a space at the start or end of your URL isn't desired, you could do something like this:

```
val str = "\n\thttp://exam\nple.com/\t\n\r".trim()
```

And it will print:

```
http://exam
ple.com/
```

Comment: How to delete characters in start of a string only?

Comment: you can use `.trimStart()` and `.trimEnd()` respectively.